# Какой должен быть формат аудио файла? или как сделать громче?

Tags: xcode

Решил прикрутить к кнопке звук
использую AudioToolbox.framework
мой код:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"my_noize" withExtension:@"mp3"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &soundID );
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

вопрос, почему так тихо?  ну на компе понятно есть колонки, громкости добавил и порядок. А вот на моём плеере когда тестирую, очень тихо!!! хотя если включить преер и проиграть музыку, оглохнуть можно от музыки, громкость девайса на полную, а звук все равно тихий

какой формат должен быть? у меня mp3 - 320kbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

формат в порядке, но *AudioServicesPlaySystemSound* подходит, в основном, для **коротких звуков интерфейса**, для **проигрывания музыки** лучше использовать **AVAudioPlayer** или **AVQueuePlayer**.